# Scheduler Spring boot

Tags: spring-batch

```
@Bean
public LockProvider lockProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(dataSource);
}


@Bean
public ScheduledLockConfiguration taskScheduler(LockProvider lockProvider) {
    return ScheduledLockConfigurationBuilder
        .withLockProvider(lockProvider)
        .withPoolSize(10)
        .withDefaultLockAtMostFor(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
        .build();
}
```

My requirement is to run only single scheduler at only one instance in clustered enviroment. For this i am using shedlock, but problem is that at server startup i am getting the below exception, "java.lang.ClassCastException: net.javacrumbs.shedlock.spring.SpringLockableTaskSchedulerFactoryBean cannot be cast to org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler"

Help me on this.

Comment: In ShedLock version 2.0.1 you should not encounter issues like this

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do this with [dlock](https://github.com/yusufaytas/dlock). You simply do the following and add registrar to your xml config.

**Java Code**

```
@TryLock(name = "doSomeWork", owner = "serviceA", lockFor = ONE_MINUTE)
public void doSomeWork() {
  //...
}
```

**XML Config**

```
<!-- A bean for the lock implementation. Note that there should be only one global implementation-->
<bean id="postgresLock" class="com.yusufaytas.dlock.jdbc.PostgresIntervalLock">
  <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="lockDataSource"/>
</bean>
<!-- The lock gets auto-registered to the registrar -->
<bean id="lockRegistrar" class="com.yusufaytas.dlock.spring.IntervalLockRegistrar"/>
```